# How to interpret ANOVA result?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I'm doing a research on factors affecting organizational culture in a company and in order to test my null and alternate hypothesis I was asked to use ANOVA on SPSS. This is the result I got for doing the ANOVA calculation for one of the independent variables and the dependent variable:

```
ANOVA
a
Model   Sum of Squares  df  Mean Square F   Sig.
1   Regression  .371    1   .371    1.639   .207
b
    Residual    10.874  48  .227        
    Total   11.246  49          
a. Dependent Variable: Organizational Culture   
b. Predictors: (Constant), Type of Work
```

How do I interpret this and have I done the calculation correctly?

Comment: ANOVAa
Model Sum of Squares df Mean Square F Sig.
1 Regression .371 1 .371 1.639 .207b
 Residual 10.874 48 .227  
 Total 11.246 49   
a. Dependent Variable: Organizational Culture   b. Predictors: (Constant), Type of Work

Answer (score 1):

ANOVA requires that the dependent variable is numerical (comparing means among groups). Is your "Organizational Culture" a numerical variable? It sounds like a categorical variable to me. In your model, you only have 0.371 for your variation, as opposed to 10.874 for your errors. I would ignore those values because it's likely that you've violated the assumptions of ANOVA. Double-check the assumptions and in particular the type of the dependent variable.